# Finding features based on total overlap of another feature class using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, select-by-location, union

I have 2 polygon feature class's (A and B) that overlap each other.

I want to select all the polygons of feature class A where the total overlapping area of feature class B polygons is less than 10m2 using ArcGIS Pro.

There may be multiple polygons overlapping

[image]

I was able to do this when there is only 1 overlapping by doing this:

1. Union of feature class A and B
2. Clip the union output with Class A feature class as clip feature
3. Definition query on the output to only show polygons with an area less than
   10m2
4. Select by location on feature class a with step 3 output as the intersecting
   feature

But I am not sure how to do this when there are more than 1 polygons of feature class B overlapping feature class A

Comment: Intersect. Summarise area in output by b polygon id. John to b table.

Comment: Thanks, This worked.

Comment: @FelixIP -See your comment above- "John to b table"?  Who is John? :)

Comment: @Hornbydd I meant Sean. Does this sound better?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not concerned with *which of the B geoms overlap the target A geom*, you might try a different approach:

**1)** Calculate the area of each feature in A -> OrigArea

**2)** Get the difference of A and B (using B as the overlay) -> Difference

**3)** Calculate the area of each feature in Difference output -> NewArea

**4)** Compute Delta = OrigArea-NewArea

**5)** Join the Difference.Delta column back to A and select where Delta < 10m2

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What software is it?

Comment: Hi @FelixIP, the images are from a quick QGIS mockup. I don't currently have an ArcDesktop license but I thought a generic approach might still be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately terminology is too different, I struggle to understand. Why do you need original area anyway?

Comment: @FelixIP, I get the original area of features in A so that I have it in the output of the Difference operation.  That way its just OrigArea-CurrentAreaOfPolygon to get the total overlapping area of features in B.